# Request type is GET when POST type is needed

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to build a simple Django application that uses forms to upload files but whenever I run my application on localhost I get the following error when trying to load the root page - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`:

> UnboundLocalError at /
>
> local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
>
> /Users/danieloram/PycharmProjects/FileUploaderProject/FileUploader/views.py in index
>
> 38. ```
>                                        {'images': images, 'form': form},
>     ```
>
>     ...
>
> ▶ Local vars

Here is the code for the relative view.py, models.py and index.html (the view in quesiton) files:

### views.py ##

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

#import models and forms
from FileUploader.models import Image
from FileUploader.forms import ImageUploadForm

# Create your views here.

#this view will respond to file uploads
def index(request):
    print("View loaded")
    if request.method =='POST':
        #create a form from the model I made
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        #check form contains no errors
        if form.is_valid():
            #create a new image and save it! file param must be name of attribute in ImageUploadForm
            newImage = Image(imageFile = request.FILES['imageFile'])
            newImage.save()
            #redirect to success page!
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
        else:
            #create an empty form if it failed
            form = ImageUploadForm()
    else:
        #view will not load as error thrown from nothing being assigned to the form.
        print("Form method was not POST! nothing was assigned to the form and it will fail.")
    images = Image.objects.all()
    #render the page and pass the dictionary to the view
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'images': images, 'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def success(request):
    debug = str(request)
    return render(request, 'success.html', {'debug': debug})
```

### models.py ##

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

#simple model for creating image objects
class Image(models.Model):
    imageFile = models.FileField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
```

### index.html ##

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "style.css" %}">
    <title>Daniel Oram's FileUploading Django Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="buffer"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <p>Choose a file to upload</p>
        <form id="form" action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="input" type="file" value="Enter Image here for upload" width="100">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" width="50">
            <!-- I need csrf_token because I used RequestContext in the view -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.imageFile.label }} {{ form.imageFile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.imageFile.error_messages }}
                {{ form.imageFile }}
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--List the files already uploaded to the webapp. -->
    <div id="list_of_Images">
        {% if images %}
        <ul>
            <!--Iterate Images stored in media directory and display a link for each -->
            {% for image in images %}
            <li><a href='{{ image.imageFile.url }}'>{{ image.imageFile.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
        <p>There are no Images that have been previously uploaded :(</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### My effort at debugging

So far I have found through debugging that the error is caused by the fact that the `form` variable is not initialized in the index method of views.py, because `if request.method =='POST':` is always evaluating to `False` because the `request` is a GET method..

Can anyone help explain to me how to make a POST request in Django and not a GET request for this context and thus solve my error and load the page. I don't even care if the form doesn't work, I just want help with a solution. thanks! **PS - The urls.py file is set up correctly.**

### Solution

in this context:

- Get request is performed when the page initially loads.
- Post request is made when form data is submitted.
- form variable needs to be initialized in order to be passed to view on initial page load.
- Else clause initializing form for the purpose of the initial page load was attached to wrong if statement and was unreachable.

## correct index method

```
def index(request):
    print("View loaded")
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newImage = Image(imageFile = request.FILES['imageFile'])
            newImage.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')       
    else:
        form = ImageUploadForm()
    images = Image.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'images': images, 'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are submitting forms in your browser, the usual workflow is:

1. You browse to the URL with a GET request
2. The browser submits data with a POST request (because the form has `action="POST"`)
3. If the form is valid, you are redirected to a successful URL

Therefore, instead of asking how to change all requests to POST, you should make your code work for the initial GET request. You can do this by creating an unbound form in the else branch.

```
    if request.method =='POST':
        # create a form bound to the post data
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        ...
    else:
        # create an unbound form for the original GET request
        form = ImageUploadForm()
        ...
```

You might find it useful to read the Django docs about [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django). The example view is very similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: omg I added the else clause to the wrong if statement... It was so simple! >_< thank you for helping me realise my error! I'm currently reading the docs on forms but I think my decision to chop and change the given examples to fit my own goal instead of completing the basic examples has caused silly logic errors like this..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the request method (obviously you first need to do a GET to have the form rendered so you can POST it), but with the fact that you *don't* bind the name "form" wjen it's a GET:

```
def index(request):
    print("View loaded")
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newImage = Image(imageFile = request.FILES['imageFile'])
            newImage.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')    

        # this part is wrong : if the validation failed,
        # you don't want to create a new empty form but
        # redisplay the failed form so you can display
        # the validation errors
        #else:
        #    #create an empty form if it failed
        #    form = ImageUploadForm()

    else:
        ## view will not load as error thrown 
        ## from nothing being assigned to the form.
        # => actually the real error is that you dont 
        #    define the *name* 'form' at all
        #    in this branch...
        #    IOW that's where you want to create 
        #    an "empty" form so the user can fill and
        #    submit it
        form = ImageUploadForm()
```